# Autodesk Forge Large Model Viewer - Suppressed Inventor Components

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-designautomation

I’m developing a configurator using the Forge Design Automation for Inventor and the large model viewer but the svf displays suppressed Inventor parts. This blog states that there is no option for the SVF to use custom levels of detail. https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/dealing-suppressed-components
So i guess the only option is to delete the suppressed components after the inserting the parameters?

Comment: I've gone the route of generating the svf myself using this example https://github.com/akenson/da-extract-params , now trying to figure out how to display the result in the viewer, is there any information available on how to do this?

Comment: Hi Connor, it looks you have solved the question yourself, based on the da-extract-params. Since this sample also saves to SVF data, you could load the SVF data in the browser by such workflow which is demoed in this sample https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-offline.sample . If you still have problem, please feel free to update this post. We will follow up

Comment: Also, here is the full sample including the server side and client side code of showing the SVF generated by DA: https://github.com/akenson/da-devcon2019/tree/master/forgesample

Comment: Thanks Both, all working now

Answer (score 0):

Posting a translation of the resultant zip with out forcing a refresh achieves this.